# Build Error in IQKeyboardManager

Tags: swift, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using IQKeyboardManager Swift2 branch via source code inclusion in my project (Xcode 7, Swift 2.0)

I get this build errors in IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler.swift and cannot imagine why they appear in my build:

[image: First build error]

[image: Second build error]

The error seems to be that the untyped(!?) content of Set should be accessible with an string index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I got these compile errors after I'd added Realm framework to my project. There should be some inconsistency between the two....

Did a simple workaround - changed this way:

> infoDict[kIQTextField] -> infoDict.objectForKey(kIQTextField)

and now all works fine I think. 
I need to fork the repo and create pull request after I double check it all works fine.

Comment: I also use Realm - and I did the same to fix it and it is working ever since.